# transform-origin doesnt apply in safari

Tags: css, safari, transform

Why doesn't transform-origin doesn't work in Safari?

Here, how it should look (Chrome): https://i.stack.imgur.com/CDkNF.png
Here, how it looks in Safari: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Zh1O.png

I already tried some stuff with percents but it my content divs are having different sizes, so it looks awkward.

Here's the JSFiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/2f4pferq/

`text-align: right;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right top;`

Here's the code:

```css
.verticaltext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 25px;
    transform: translateX(-100%);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.verticaltext_content {
    text-align: right;
    -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -ms-transform-origin: right top;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: right top;
    transform: rotate(-90deg);
    transform-origin: right top;
}

.content {
    background-color: #000;
    color: #FFF;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
    padding: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 200px;
}

.content p {
    margin: 0px 0px 0px 30px;
}

.content ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.content a,
.content a:link,
.content a:visited {
    color: #FFF;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.content a:hover {
    color: #FFA500;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content i.fa {
    color: #FFF;
    width: 15%;
}

.content i.fa:hover {
    color: #FFA500;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="verticaltext">
    <h2 class="verticaltext_content">Diskografie</h2>
  </div>
 
  
 <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of pasting your code make a jsfiddle please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2f4pferq/ @Ace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your not vendor prefixing for the `.verticaltext` on your transform

```css
.verticaltext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25px;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Should be

```css
.verticaltext {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25px;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-100%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-100%);
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```