# CSS Rotation, Translate, Scale Animation Bug

Tags: safari, css-animations

I have created an animation for HTML/CSS3 using keyframes.

The animation is of an icon that is supposed to rotate and scale around its centre point.

The animation works in Chrome, but in Safari it doesn't properly translate until the end of the animation.

Here it is – snapping into position – in **safari**:

[image]

Here it is – smoothly animating into position – in **chrome**:

[image]

Here is the animation CSS:

```
@keyframes icon-animation {
    0% {
        left: 188.5px;
        top: 187.5px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        width: 286.84px;
        height: 233.81px;
    }
    16.6667% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
    }
    50% {
        left: 188px;
        top: 188.5px;
    }
    66.6667% {
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 163px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 188px;
        top: 188.5px;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg);
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        width: 200px;
        height: 163px;
    }
}
```

***The HTML and Default CSS are long-ish so I've created a codepen example, which can be found here:***

https://codepen.io/traviskirton/pen/NLdKbb

Comment: vendor prefixing? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30688908/transform-origin-doesnt-apply-in-safari

Comment: @C4 - Travis  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin . See Compatibility table .

Comment: @undefinedMayNotBeNull tried it.

Answer (score 2):

Despite being quite possibly a Safari specific bug, I wouldn't personally mess up too much with static pixels computation + top and left adjustment.

What you are basically doing there, is reducing the image size by 30%.

You can easily achieve the same via `scale`.

Following a simplified version of your animation that works as expected in Safari too.

```
@keyframes icon-animation {
    0% {
        transform-origin: 50% 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(-45deg);
    }
    100% {
      transform-origin: 50% 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(0deg) scale(.70);
    }
}
```

If `scale` is not an option, you should try to play with margins but that might have undesired behavior in Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: The scale approach may/maynot be possible for us. We have some tight constraints on our end that require us to write code in a particular way. There might be a middle-ground solution between your answer and @menelaos-bakopoulos above.

Answer (score 2):

### Intro

I would actually simplify your code.
I checked the **compatibility** table for `transform-origin` and it doesn't really match with safari. There is a question mark about `transform-origin svg support` and it also required a `-webkit-` vendor prefix that just makes things quite complicated for the simple effect you want.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin
[image]

I was able to get the **exact same effect**, just by commenting various things ( and modifying the left/top values for some keyframes). **And this works perfectly in both safari and chrome.**

### Example - Online

I tested both your example, and mine, on my mobile safari:
https://codepen.io/menelaosbgr/pen/pOpXbB

### Code:

```
@keyframes icon-animation {
    0% {
        left: 71px; 
         top: 90px;
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
/*         transform-origin: 50% 50%; */
        width: 286.84px;
        height: 233.81px;
    }
    16.6667% {
/*         left: 188px;
        top: 188.5px; */
        transform: rotate(-45deg);
/*         transform-origin: 50% 50%; */
    }
    50% {
/*         left: 188px;
        top: 188.5px; */
    }
    66.6667% {
/*         left: 188px;
        top: 188.5px; */
        transform:  rotate(0deg);
/*         transform-origin: 50% 50%; */
        width: 200px;
        height: 163px;
    }
    100% {
        left: 90px; 
         top: 90px;
        transform: rotate(0deg);
/*         transform-origin: 50% 50%; */
        width: 200px;
        height: 163px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks. We actually have some tight constraints around how we write our css which is why I am specifically asking about the approach I posted above. There might be a middle ground between your answer and @andrea-giammarchi's idea. I'll have to experiment.